"Error in Ops.data.frame(guide_loc, panel_loc) : ‘==’ only defined for equally-sized data frames" when using draw() from gratia to draw GAM in r
I am trying to draw GAMs in R using the below code. This code always used to work, and I could draw the partial effect of my smoothed term, but randomly it no longer works, consistently triggering this error:
Error in Ops.data.frame(guide_loc, panel_loc) : 
  ‘==’ only defined for equally-sized data frames


My code looks like the following:
library(mgcv)
library(gratia)

gam1 <- mgcv::gam(mpg ~ cyl +
                          s(disp), data = mtcars, method = "REML")

draw(gam1)

# directly drawing function from the package also triggers the error

gratia::draw(gam1)



The error message I receive makes no sense to me, as I do not see how it implicates data frame size (or at least not multiple data frames as the wording suggests.
This error first emerged when I attempted to take the derivatives of the model and draw them instead, with the following code:

derivatives1 <- derivatives(gam1,
                             term = "s(disp)",
                            order = 1L,
                             type = "central",
                             n = 250,
                             eps = 1,
                             interval = "simultaneous",
                             n_sim = 500000,
                             unconditional = TRUE)

draw(derivatives1)



which draws the same error:
Error in Ops.data.frame(guide_loc, panel_loc) : 
  ‘==’ only defined for equally-sized data frames


But now this error happens anytime I try to draw a gam, or its derivatives. I have tried restarting r and unloading packages to ensure no package conflict is causing this, but the error still emerges.
How can I resolve this error and draw my GAMs and derivatives of the GAMs' smooths?
Update
Here is my session info:
R version 4.3.3 (2024-02-29)
Platform: aarch64-apple-darwin20 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Sonoma 14.4

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib 
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-arm64/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib;  LAPACK version 3.11.0

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

time zone: America/New_York
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] kableExtra_1.3.4   mediation_4.5.0    mvtnorm_1.2-4      MASS_7.3-60.0.1    sandwich_3.1-0     schoenberg_2.0.3  
 [7] mgcViz_0.1.11      qgam_1.3.4         viridis_0.6.5      viridisLite_0.4.2  tidymv_3.4.2       scales_1.3.0      
[13] gamm4_0.2-6        mgcv_1.9-1         nlme_3.1-164       modelsummary_1.4.1 sjPlot_2.8.14      ggpubr_0.6.0      
[19] gridExtra_2.3      lme4_1.1-35.2      Matrix_1.6-5       countrycode_1.5.0  labelled_2.11.0    haven_2.5.4       
[25] lubridate_1.9.2    forcats_1.0.0      stringr_1.5.1      dplyr_1.1.4        purrr_1.0.2        readr_2.1.5       
[31] tidyr_1.3.1        tibble_3.2.1       ggplot2_3.5.0      tidyverse_2.0.0    gratia_0.9.0      
     

Update 2
Here is the traceback on the error from a clean session in which only mgcv and gratia are loaded:
10: stop(gettextf("%s only defined for equally-sized data frames", 
        sQuote(.Generic)), domain = NA)
9: Ops.data.frame(guide_loc, panel_loc)
8: unlist(guide_loc == panel_loc)
7: add_guides(gt, guides == "collect")
6: plot_table.ggplot(X[[i]], ...)
5: FUN(X[[i]], ...)
4: lapply(x$plots, plot_table, guides = guides)
3: build_patchwork(plot, plot$layout$guides %||% "auto")
2: print.patchwork(x)
1: (function (x, ...) 
   UseMethod("print"))(x)

and here is the session info for that clean session:
R version 4.3.3 (2024-02-29)
Platform: aarch64-apple-darwin20 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Sonoma 14.4

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib 
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-arm64/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib;  LAPACK version 3.11.0

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

time zone: America/New_York
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] gratia_0.9.0 mgcv_1.9-1   nlme_3.1-164

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Matrix_1.6-5       mvnfast_0.2.8      gtable_0.3.4       dplyr_1.1.4        compiler_4.3.3     tidyselect_1.2.1  
 [7] Rcpp_1.0.12        stringr_1.5.1      tidyr_1.3.1        splines_4.3.3      scales_1.3.0       yaml_2.3.8        
[13] fastmap_1.1.1      lattice_0.22-5     ggplot2_3.5.0      R6_2.5.1           labeling_0.4.3     generics_0.1.3    
[19] patchwork_1.1.3    knitr_1.45         tibble_3.2.1       munsell_0.5.0      RColorBrewer_1.1-3 pillar_1.9.0      
[25] rlang_1.1.3        utf8_1.2.4         stringi_1.8.3      xfun_0.43          cli_3.6.2          withr_3.0.0       
[31] magrittr_2.0.3     digest_0.6.35      grid_4.3.3         rstudioapi_0.16.0  lifecycle_1.0.4    ggokabeito_0.1.0  
[37] vctrs_0.6.5        evaluate_0.23      glue_1.7.0         farver_2.1.1       fansi_1.0.6        colorspace_2.1-0  
[43] purrr_1.0.2        rmarkdown_2.26     tools_4.3.3        pkgconfig_2.0.3    htmltools_0.5.8.1 


You must either have an old version of {gratia} (though I doubt I've ever seen this error reported for a CRAN-released version of the package - if you installed from GitHub, update your package from CRAN to get version 0.9.0) or have some other package loaded that is masking or otherwise interacting badly with {gratia}.
With the CRAN release of {gratia} I can't reproduce your problem.
r$> library(mgcv) 
    library(gratia) 
     
    gam1 <- mgcv::gam(mpg ~ cyl + 
                              s(disp), data = mtcars, method = "REML") 
     
    draw(gam1) 
     
    # directly drawing function from the package also triggers the error 
     
    gratia::draw(gam1)                                                          
Loading required package: nlme
This is mgcv 1.9-1. For overview type 'help("mgcv-package")'.

r$> derivatives1 <- derivatives(gam1, 
                                 term = "s(disp)", 
                                order = 1L, 
                                 type = "central", 
                                 n = 250, 
                                 eps = 1, 
                                 interval = "simultaneous", 
                                 n_sim = 500000, 
                                 unconditional = TRUE) 
     
    draw(derivatives1)                                                          
Warning message:
The `term` argument of `derivatives()` is deprecated as of gratia 0.8.9.9.
ℹ Please use the `select` argument of `derivativess()` instead.
This warning is displayed once every 8 hours.
Call `lifecycle::last_lifecycle_warnings()` to see where this warning was
generated. 

(You can ignore the warning; if it bothers you, change term = "s(disp)" to be select = "s(disp)".

Thanks for the reply and explanation. Oddly, I tried restarting R, downloading from CRAN to make sure I have updated to 0.9.0, and having no other packages loaded except for base r, but I still get the same error: Error in Ops.data.frame(guide_loc, panel_loc) :    ‘==’ only defined for equally-sized data frames

Can you post your sessionInfo() in your question please: it would be good to know if you are running an up to date R as if you aren't that might limit the version of gratia you can install/upgrade to.

I have updated the question with the session info. I was indeed using a slightly older version, but after updating the error still occurs unfortunately.

@flâneur can you try running in a clean session; you have quite a few packages loaded that aren’t due to gratia. In a clean session, just load mgcv and gratia and run your model. If the error persists then, there is something wrong in gratia, but I suspect you’ll find the error goes away and if so it implies that one of the other packages you have loaded is what is causing the problem. Narrowing this down would be helpful (as I might be able to do something about it) but you might not want to spend all that time loading combinations of packages to identify the source of the error

@flâneur another useful output would be the trace back at the point that you get the error. Immediately after you get the error, run traceback() and post the output in to your question, and I’ll see if something stands out.

Thanks for your continued patience and dedication to this. I've updated the question with the traceback and session info for a clean session (in this case, also an entirely new r project and .rmd file as well)

It's probably an issue with ggplot and or patchwork. Make sure you update all your packages; your ggplot is out of date, current version is 3.5.1 for example. Basically quite R, start a new clean session, run update.packages(ask = FALSE, checkBuilt = TRUE, Ncpus = 3) setting Ncpus to however many CPU cores you want to use install packages in parallel and let it run. It's almost certainly a problem due to incompatabilities between packages as not all are up to date.

This worked! Thank you so much for taking all the time to go through this over what was a simple mistake on my part. I truly appreciate it. Also, I must say that apart from anything else, your gratia package is absolutely stellar!

Thanks @flâneur and glad we got this figured out
